# Problem creating headers of axios request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, express, axios

When I create a JSON object like this

```
let headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Hasura-Role": "user",
    "Authorization": "Bearer sadasdasdasdasdadsasdab0d8528",

};
    console.log(headers);
```

It gives result like this

```
{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  Authorization: 'Bearer sadasdasdasdasdadsasdab0d8528',
  'X-Hasura-Role': 'user' }
```

but I want it like this

```
{ 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer sadasdasdasdasdadsasdab0d8528',
  'X-Hasura-Role': 'user' }
```

I am really confused about what is going on. I am using express and axios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want and what you get are the same thing.

The presence or absence of quotes around the Authorization property name is just an artefact of the tool you are using to inspect the object.

The underlying data is identical.